# Backup Plus Portable Drive won't Mount

Tags: macbook-pro

I plug my Backup Plus Portable Drive (Seagate) into my MacBook Air (10.13.3 MacOS High Sierra Version) into my USB ports, both of them.  The drive lights up, I can hear it running however it is not showing up in Finder.  I have searched the Web for all sorts of solutions however I am unable to find any and Seagate was no help.

thanks for any help, this drive holds valuable information that I need to at most get off of it so I can throw it into a fire pit.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Open Disk Utility and see if your external drive appears. Find Disk Utility in Applications > Utilities > Disk Utility. If your drive shows up but is not mounted, select the mount option which should mount that disk. To verify, click on the Apple logo in your screen's top left corner and select About This Mac.